# Extracting substring by positions in pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I would like to extract substring from every row of the `id` column of a tibble. I am interested always in a region between 1st and 3rd space of original `id`. The resulted substring, so `Zoe Boston` and `Jane Rome`, would go to the new column - `name`.

I tried to get the positions of "spaces" in every id with `str_locate_all` and then use positions to use `str_sub`. However I cannot extract the positions correctly.

```
data <- tibble(id = c("#1265746 Zoe Boston 58962 st. Victory cont_1.0)", "#958463279246 Jane Rome 874593.01 musician band: XYZ 985147") ) %>% 
   mutate(coor =  str_locate_all(id, "\\s"),
   name = str_sub(id, start = coor[[1]], end = coor[[3]] ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract what you want.

Assuming you have stored your tibble in `data`, you can use `sub` to extract 1st and 2nd word.

```
sub('^#\\w+\\s(\\w+\\s\\w+).*', '\\1', data$id)
#[1] "Zoe Boston" "Jane Rome"
```

`^#` - starts with hash

`\\w+` -  A word

`\\s` - Whitespace

`(` - start of capture group

`\\w+` - A word

followed by `\\s` - whitespace

`\\w+` - another word

`)` - end of capture group.

`.*` - remaining string.

---

The `str_locate` is more complex, since it first returns the position of whitespace then you need to select the end of 1st whitespace and start of 3rd and then use `str_sub` to extract text between those positions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

data %>%
   mutate(coor =  str_locate_all(id, "\\s"), 
          start = map_dbl(coor, `[`, 1) + 1, 
          end = map_dbl(coor, `[`, 3) - 1,
          name = str_sub(id, start, end))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  id                                                          name      
#  <chr>                                                       <chr>     
#1 #1265746 Zoe Boston 58962 st. Victory cont_1.0)             Zoe Boston
#2 #958463279246 Jane Rome 874593.01 musician band: XYZ 985147 Jane Rome
```

Comment: could you explain the `regex` behind?

Comment: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using `stringr` and `purrr` packages

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(name = map_chr(str_split(id, " "), ~paste(unlist(.)[2:3], collapse = " ")))
```

Explanation:

- in `str_split(id, " ")` we create a list of the terms that are separated inside `id` by a whitespace
- `map_chr` is useful to take each one of these lists, and apply the following function to them: unlist the list, take the elements in positions 2 and 3 (which are the `name` we want) and then collapse them with a whitespace between them

---

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   id                                                          name      
#   <chr>                                                       <chr>     
# 1 #1265746 Zoe Boston 58962 st. Victory cont_1.0)             Zoe Boston
# 2 #958463279246 Jane Rome 874593.01 musician band: XYZ 985147 Jane Rome
```